# Where are all of the XML error codes documented?

Tags: xml, windows-runtime

In the Windows Runtime the DOM classes (XmlDocument) result in case of errors in a COM error with HRESULT value. Most of the error codes are documented (for MSXML) in the [MSXML documentation / XML Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj134410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But I could not find the documentation of other error codes. For example when trying to load an XML document having elements named using a namespace prefix that is not declared, HRESULT 0xC00CE01D results. The HRESULT codes in the mentioned documentation start with 0xC00CEE00, 0xC00CE01D is not mentioned there. I suppose there is a whole range of HRESULT values missing in the documentation (possible 0xC00CE000 to 0xC00CEDFF).

Does anyone know where I could find the documentation of missing HRESULT values for XML?

Comment: +1 So 0xC00CE01D is thrown when trying to load an XML document having elements named using a namespace prefix that is not declared. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks CSharper :-) At least my still unanswered question did help someone.

Answer (score 1):

See the Microsoft [XML Lite Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The error codes are defined in xmllite.h.  Many of them are the same as the errors in MSXML.